# Use version catalog when substitute module in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have dependency substitution rules:

```
allprojects {
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
      // add dependency substitution rules
      dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('group1:module1') with module("group2:module2:1.0.0")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I replace "group2:module2:1.0.0" with versions catalog?

When I try:

```
substitute module('group1:module1') with module(libs.module2)
```

it fails:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'build.gradle' line: 264
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'demo'.
>
> > Could not find method module() for arguments [provider(?)] on object of type
> > org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.dependencysubstitution.DefaultDependencySubstitutions

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution.

libs.versions.toml:

```
[versions]
module2Version= "1.0.0"
```

and 'build.gradle' file:

```
substitute module('group1:module1') with module("group2:module2:${libs.versions.module2Version.get()}")
```